# Set NSFontAttributeName to have bold font

Tags: ios, swift, nsfont

Im trying to apply on the following code to be bold with current custom font , how do i include it in the dictionary ?

```
let normalWhite = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "somefont", size: 16.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  You want to add those values to an existing dictionary, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should include the custom bold font file in your Xcode and write its name like `Helvetica-Bold`